# A função deveria calcular o tamanho de uma string, passando uma string como paramentro

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/*Função que verifica tamanho da string*/
int conta_str(char x){

    int i, tamanho = 0;
    char str[40];
        do{

            gets(str);

                for(i = 0, tamanho = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++){
                    if(str[i] == '\0'){
                        break;
                    }
                    tamanho++;
                }

            if(tamanho < 8){
                printf("Tamanho inferior a 8 caracteres...");
            }
        }while(tamanho < 8);



return tamanho;
}


int main(){
    char str[40];
    gets(str);

    conta_str(str);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? Sugiro também que leia as diretrizes da comunidade de como fazer uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Opa Paulo. Assim fica difícil te ajudar, edite sua pergunta e explique o que você está tentando fazer e qual o erro que está acontecendo.

Comment: Você definiu sua função com o parâmetro sendo um caractere único (char x) mas chama a função passando um array de caracteres conta_str(str);, além disso sua função não faz absolutamente nada com o parâmetro.

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância gnt. Estou engatinhando nesse mundo da programação.

Comment: @PauloMaciel leia o link que te mandei, volte aqui e corrija!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma possível alternativa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Função que verifica tamanho da string*/
int conta_str(char x[]){
    int i=0;
    while (x[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    if (i < 8) {
        printf("Tamanho inferior a 8 caracteres...");
        return -1;
    }
   else
        return i;
}


int main(){
    char str[40];
    int tamanho;
    gets(str);
    tamanho = conta_str(str);
    if (tamanho == -1)
        printf("Tamanho inferior a 8 caracteres...");
    else
        printf("Tamanho de %s: %d\n", str, tamanho);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. parece que nesse caso era só passar o vetor como parâmetro e nao um unico caracter. valew pela ajuda